# IOS - Objective C - How to delete UItextfield programmatically when pickerView Element is selected?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I am creating a `UITextfield` programmatically when an item is selected from my `pickerview` using this code:

```
UITextField * mytextfield = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 243, 225, 30)];
                                 [self.view addSubview: mytextfield];
        mytextfield.placeholder = @"my placeholder..." ;   //for place holder
        mytextfield.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;     //adjust the font size to fit width.

        mytextfield.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];             //text color
        mytextfield.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;        //keyboard type of ur choice
        mytextfield.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;              //returnKey type for keyboard
        mytextfield.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;//for clear button on right side
```

What I want to do is to delete this `UITextfield` that I created when another item is selected from my `picker view`

I can't seem to figure out how to do it, any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a @property that holds your TextField. Then do [self.myTextField removeFromSuperView]; when needed.

Comment: the removeFromSuperView method actually deletes it from the UI, but when I NSLog it , the UITextfield is still there , is there a way to remove it permanetly ?

Comment: self.myTextfield = nil?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove text field by

```
[mytextfield removeFromSuperView];
```

Comment: the removeFromSuperView method actually deletes it from the UI, but when I NSLog it , the UITextfield is still there , is there a way to remove it permanetly ?

Comment: @samouray Actually with ARC, you cannot release an object whenever you want. It will automatically be removed when the reference count reaches to 0. In non ARC, we had the option to release on our whim.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your textfield to a `weak` property it should be deallocated after it has been removed from its superview albeit not immediately. If you have set it to `strong` you can do the following:

```
[self.myTextField removeFromSuperview];
self.myTextField = nil;
```